# Mismatch in IOS useragent

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-agent

We have received today an useragent looking like this:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E216 Myapp/10.2.0.3 (iPad4,4; iOS 11.3; gzip)

According to what i know from the mozilla specs the system details tell us it's and iphone and the platform details tell us it's an ipad?

Did somebody encounter this scenario before, and knows if we should detect it as an iphone or an ipad?

specs mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

As far as it concerns me it's an iphone, but am not 100% sure if i'm interpreting it correctly?

Comment: It looks like the client app incorrectly built it's User-Agent. They could hardcode the `iPhone` string and add a correct device type to the platform details section. For instance, here's a default User-Agent string from Mobile Safari:
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/42.0.183854831 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out after time, that we are simply hitting fraud scenario's that try to pass both checks. So the fraudsters tries if it matches on one of both conditions. Topic closed.